# OWL: complementary behavior in equivalent class definition

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, pellet

In the following ontology we have eliminate `Pizza` in equivalent definition of `VegaterainPizza`. also domain of `hasTopping` is `Pizza`.

[image]

after executing the pellet,the following result is deduced.

[image]

[image]

I need to know why `Pizza` is equivalent to `Thing` and `Food`?

Comment: Because the axioms **i)** `VegetarianPizza EquivalentTo not (hasTopping some PizzaTopping)` and **ii)** `hasTopping Domain Pizza` and **iii)** `VegetarianPizza SubClassOf Pizza` and **iv)** `Pizza SubClassOf Food` entail the axiom `Food EquivalentTo Pizza` - just build the subclass chain and see it. Hint: `hasTopping Domain Pizza` is logically equivalent to `hasTopping some Thing SubClassOf Pizza`. Moreover, you have `not (hasTopping some PizzaTopping) SubClassOf VegetarianPizza` - the rest is up to you and straightforward

Comment: @AKSW thanks.but it is not obvious to me . If you remove `not` from `Vegaterian` definition , then , `pizza` is not equivalent to `Food` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by AKSW:

Simplifying the names to make the axioms shorter:
`VegetarianPizza` named `V`
`hasTopping` named `h`
`Pizza` named `P`
`PizzaTopping` named `PT`
`Food` named `F`

```
V equivalent to not (h some PT)
h domain P
V subclass P
```

Now, consider any individual, with or without assertions for the property h.

```
a h b
```

implies `a` is of type `P`

For any other individuals `c`, `d`... without assertions with property `h`, they belong to `not( h some PT)`, which is defined as equivalent to `V`. And `V` is defined as subclass of `P`.

So, *no matter* whether an individual has an `h` filer (i.e., has a topping) or not, it ends up being an instance of `P`; therefore `P` is equivalent to `owl:Thing`, and so is every superclass of `P`, in this case `F`.

As you mention, removing the `not` changes this result. This is because without the `not` `P` no longer includes all individuals.

Comment: thanks. as far as i know In OWA we have three modes: `true, false, unknown`. But you only considered it to be `true, false`, which is related to CWA. I mean, if we don't assert `c h PT`, can we conclude that `c not (h PT)`?

Comment: OWA does not matter here because the class complement is used; their union is always equivalent to owl:Thing even if the reasoner cannot infer whether an individual belongs to one or the other.